# Using a SVN repo file as a source for an XML data provider

Tags: wpf, svn, c#-3.0, xmldataprovider

As title really, how/is it possible to set the `Source` property of an `XmlDataProvider` to use a file held on our SVN repository?

I've tried this:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="xmlDPPlatforms" Source="https://[path to xml file]" />
```

But it doesn't work, which I'm guessing is down to the fact that it's held on a secure (HTTPS) repository? It doesn't throw any errors, but nothing which relies on the file get's populated.

I know I could theoretically use svn commands to download the latest version into a stream/string, and bind that to the dataprovider, but that seems a bit convoluted to me?

Running on .net 3.5 framework, but no qualms about upgrading it to 4 if need be.

Thanks

Comment: I'll resist the temptation to ask "why" you're using a version control system for this - unless you want to tell us :) - and instead ask you to clarify the error. You say "it doesn't work", what is the SVN server actually returning? Are you authenticating correctly?

Comment: Because it'll then be in a location which is editable by everybody in the company, so the app wont require re-publishing every time we update it. I don't know what SVN is returning, but I'm guessing is an authentication issue, when I say it isn't working, the app runs fine, no exceptions, but the source doesn't get populated.

Answer (score 0):

check the apache access/error logs when the client should be getting the file.  maybe it's authentication or authorization related